# Nagios: check local interface statistics

Tags: nagios

Is there any simple solution (nagios check script) to monitor local interface statistics?
Of course I could do it by SNMP (e.g. check_snmp_int) but I don't think it is necessary to run SNMP agent for that.

Comment: What sort of local interface?  NIC?  USB?  PS/2?  SCSI?  What sort of statistics?  I beg you, please be specific!

Comment: Actually I have not found what I was looking for. There are scripts like stat_net.pl and check_netio but they only give total amount of data rx/tx. What I need is **bandwidth utilization** and unfortunately I could not find any script for that. Of course I could write (or even rewrite from e.g. check_snmp_int) some code to write data to file and then do some arithmetic, but I still hope that this work is already done.
So if you guys know about such a script, please share! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried it, but a quick Google search turned up [check_iflocal](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_iflocal/details), and there are others in the [Networking subcategory within the Metrics category](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Networking).

There are many SNMP variants out there, and not all of them make it onto the Exchange. Even then, you might find multiple different plugins with the same name.

I'm not sure if this is the same as "check_bandwidth3" on the Exchange, but you might want to try [check_bandwidth](http://code.google.com/p/check-bandwidth/). If you're still bent on not using SNMP, maybe give [this guy's method](http://www.vanstechelman.eu/linux/nagios_check_bandwidth_usage_plugin) a try.

Comment: I had already tried to find something like that at Nagios Exchange before I asked this question but with no luck. After your suggestion though I finally managed to find the right plugin.
check_iflocal only checks for errors/drops but there is another one which will perfectly work for me: [stat_net.pl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Networking/stat_net-2Epl/details)
Thanks! :)

Comment: The only "interface statistics" worth alerting on are errors on drops, IMHO ;-)

Comment: Besides I can not fully agree with you on this, monitoring is not only about alerting. ;-)
On the other hand, as MadHatter already pointed out, I didn't even mention what kind of statistics I was asking about... :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already looked for something suitable on monitoringexchange and not found it,
assuming it is an Ethernet interface, you could write a plugin that calls ifconfig or ip or ethtool or reads the appropriate info from procfs/sysfs and parses that information...

Comment: Sure. Nevertheless I don't like to reinvent the wheel. :)